# How to rename plugin "Booking Activities" in wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to rename the plugin name (Booking Activities) from this plugin to any custom name:

[image]

I've tried it whith changin the name in the header like this:

```
<?php  
/**
 * Plugin Name: Gästebuchungen
...
*/
```

but this don't work for me.

Update:

I've found this in the plugin root folder:

```
function bookacti_create_menu() {
    // Add a menu and submenus
    $icon_url = 'dashicons-calendar-alt';
    add_menu_page( __( 'Booking Activities', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), _x( 'Booking Activities', 'Name of the tab in the menu', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), 'bookacti_manage_booking_activities', 'booking-activities', null, $icon_url, '56.5' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', _x( 'Booking Activities', 'Landing page title', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), _x( 'Home', 'Landing page tab name', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),'bookacti_manage_booking_activities',           'booking-activities',   'bookacti_landing_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Calendar editor', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                          __( 'Calendar editor', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),              'bookacti_manage_templates',                    'bookacti_calendars',   'bookacti_templates_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Booking forms', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                            __( 'Booking forms', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                'bookacti_manage_forms',                        'bookacti_forms',       'bookacti_forms_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Bookings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                                 __( 'Bookings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                     'bookacti_manage_bookings',                     'bookacti_bookings',    'bookacti_bookings_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Settings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                                 __( 'Settings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                     'bookacti_manage_booking_activities_settings',  'bookacti_settings',    'bookacti_settings_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'bookacti_create_menu' );
```

I've changed the text to this:

```
function bookacti_create_menu() {
    // Add a menu and submenus
    $icon_url = 'dashicons-calendar-alt';
    add_menu_page( __( '**Gästebuchungen**', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), _x( '**Gästebuchungen**', 'Name of the tab in the menu', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), 'bookacti_manage_booking_activities', 'booking-activities', null, $icon_url, '56.5' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', _x( '**Gästebuchungen**', 'Landing page title', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ), _x( 'Home', 'Landing page tab name', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),'bookacti_manage_booking_activities',           'booking-activities',   'bookacti_landing_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Calendar editor', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                          __( 'Calendar editor', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),              'bookacti_manage_templates',                    'bookacti_calendars',   'bookacti_templates_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Booking forms', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                            __( 'Booking forms', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                'bookacti_manage_forms',                        'bookacti_forms',       'bookacti_forms_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Bookings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                                 __( 'Bookings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                     'bookacti_manage_bookings',                     'bookacti_bookings',    'bookacti_bookings_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'booking-activities', __( 'Settings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                                 __( 'Settings', BOOKACTI_PLUGIN_NAME ),                     'bookacti_manage_booking_activities_settings',  'bookacti_settings',    'bookacti_settings_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'bookacti_create_menu' );
```

After this the plugin has an error with loading all form and adding new ones.

Comment: Find where the plugin uses the `admin_menu` hook. [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus)

Comment: I've found it and tried to change it. Please take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay for you to use a free plugin, please search after „admin menu editor“.

After you‘ve successfully installed the plugin you can go to „Settings“->“Menu Editor“ and rename any menu entry. Hope that helps.

EDIT:
This works only for the menu title, not for the header title inside the plugin.